# Hindrances of having many UIView in a single UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is it okay for an app to contain many  Custom UIViews using a single UIViewController? I'm afraid that my apps would go slow if i will push this idea using single UIViewController and hide and show the UIView that I would like to show whenever a button/menu i clicked. 
Is this idea advisable or not?? Please give me some idea.

Here is what I did with my project:

[image]

As you can see I only have one UIViewController and I add UIView which are Content, MyPage, News, Schedule, Information, and Login..

Comment: @Caleb - how many is "many" doesn't matter. 1000 views of a single background color will be different than 1000 views holding a lot of RAM with an image and doing complex drawRect. .

Comment: @JasperBlues I can't think of a real-world case where 1000 views containing nothing but a background color would be useful, and as the OP is asking about custom views I assume that's not what he or she is doing.

Comment: @Caleb That's not the point. You've definitely missed that. (And possibly I think the question . . or I have). But the point is, it depends what the view is doing. . The way I interpreted the question was "Is it a good idea to have one VC that presents different content views based on menu clicks" . . My answer explains that no, this is not a good approach.

Comment: @JasperBlues Frankly, the OP should be a lot more specific. For that reason, I'm voting to close as unclear. The way I read the question, the OP is talking about having a single view with many (whatever that means) subviews where some of those subviews are displayed or hidden based on user actions.

Comment: @khatz0406 Could you be more specific, please? As you can see from the comments above, it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Caleb What i'm trying to do is to put all my views in a single UIViewController.. I'll post some screen shot of what i'm trying to do.. Sorry for the late response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its generally not how many views you have that matters, but what you're doing with them.

**Typical Performance Bottlenecks:**

- Views that are doing lots of custom drawing (drawRect) will tend to be good candidates for optimization.
- Similarly, complex manipulations of CALayer or animations can also cause performance bottlenecks and require extra attention.

. . while experience will help you to predict what is likely to cause a performance problem, its generally best to leave optimization until you observe an actual problem - ie based on a real measurement with a profiling tool.

**Correct Structure**

You should structure your application so that you have:

- A root view controller responsible for managing the main layout of your window. (Swipe to reveal menus, main content area, title bar, etc). . . For a typical app you could just use a UINavigationController (or similar UIKit provided class) as the root. For something more complex you could make your own. This is called UIViewController ***containment***, and you can Google about it (or follow the link in the other answer).
- Within the root view controller you can add child view controllers. These child view controllers in turn have their own view and hierarchy. ***You should interact with these child vies via their controller and not with the view directly***. . . This will give you a much more maintainable code-base, and will be true to the MVC pattern's intentions.

**Summary:**

- No harm with respect to performance from having lots of sub-views. It more depends on what the sub-views are doing.
- Your sub-views should none-the-less be managed by a controller hierarchy, and not just one master view controller. This way you'll have less code maintenance problems.

Comment: In addition to being wrong (the number of views *can* become a significant issue, which is why tables and collections minimize the number of cells via recycling), this really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: a) To me it seemed like @khatz0406 was asking if he could have just one view controller responsible for hiding/showing a number of views, which seems more like the job of a controller b) Its just an elaboration of the other answer (which is up-voted) - he also suggests containment. c) I was speaking generally - the number of views will impact less than what they're doing. . . the most important point is a)

Comment: You got what I'm trying to ask @JasperBlues..as I understand based from your previous comment it is not advisable because if a single UIView will do lot function the app will go slow..due to memory allocation..

Comment: @katz0406 - Walang anuman pare. . NB: Its not so much about memory, but about code maintainability. Each "screen" (or content area) should have its own controller. . . The controller acts as glue between the "model" (where you use OO concepts to model your problem domain) and view - which is all about user interaction.

Answer (score 4):

Once you get to a few hundred it may slow down, but its normal to manipulate subviews.

Sometimes its useful to make a screen of multiple view controllers, see here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html